# Image thumbnails Django Backblaze B2

Tags: python, django

I am building a photo viewing and storing website using Django and Backblaze B2 and I have a lot of large (filesize) photo's that I am planning to upload on it.

My plan was to use thumbnails for photo browsing, these need to be generated automatically. Photo's are uploaded to Django, which in turn uploads the photo to B2, then it downloads it again, creates a thumbnail and uploads the thumbnail to B2.

The downloading of the full-size image step seems unnessecary to me as the file is already uploaded through the Django webserver. Couldn't Django just keep the uploaded photo in memory (or temporary local storage), build a thumbnail and upload both the full-size image and the thumbnail to B2 afterwards?

I am using the code below to generate a thumbnail in the `save()` step of the `Photo` model and it works. I am just looking for a way to make this more efficient without downloading the full-size image again. I thought about doing this in the `PhotoForm` with an overridden `save()` method but I was not able to find how to do this. I also have included the code of the custom `B2Storage` class.

If anyone could give me an approach I should be taking I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

#### models/photo.py

```
import os
from io import BytesIO

from PIL import Image
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.db import models

from fotoplatform.storage import B2Storage

THUMB_SIZE = (400, 400)


class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.ImageField(storage=B2Storage(), unique=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(storage=B2Storage(), unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.thumbnail:
             self.make_thumbnail()
        super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def make_thumbnail(self):
        try:
            image = Image.open(self.photo)
        except:
            raise Exception('Unable to open photo')

        image.thumbnail(THUMB_SIZE, Image.ANTIALIAS)

        thumb_name, thumb_extension = os.path.splitext(self.photo.name)
        thumb_extension = thumb_extension.lower()

        thumb_filename = thumb_name + '_thumb' + thumb_extension

        if thumb_extension in ['.jpg', '.jpeg']:
            FTYPE = 'JPEG'
        elif thumb_extension == '.gif':
            FTYPE = 'GIF'
        elif thumb_extension == '.png':
            FTYPE = 'PNG'
        else:
            raise Exception("Unknown extension")

        temp_thumb = BytesIO()
        image.save(temp_thumb, FTYPE)
        temp_thumb.seek(0)

        self.thumbnail.save(thumb_filename, ContentFile(temp_thumb.read()), save=True)
        temp_thumb.close()
```

#### forms.py

```
import logging

from django import forms

from fotoplatform.models import Photo


class PhotoForm(LoggingMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    photo = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))

    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields = ['title', 'photo']
```

#### storage.py

```
import hashlib
import logging
import os
import re

from b2blaze import B2
from django.core.files.storage import Storage
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible

from dsbfotoplatform import settings

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

b2 = B2(key_id=settings.B2_KEY_ID, application_key=settings.B2_APPLICATION_KEY)
bucket = b2.buckets.get(bucket_id=settings.B2_BUCKET_ID)

@deconstructible
class B2Storage(Storage):

    def path(self, name):
        pass

    def delete(self, name):
        pass

    def exists(self, name):
        pass

    def listdir(self, path):
        pass

    def size(self, name):
        pass

    def get_accessed_time(self, name):
        pass

    def get_created_time(self, name):
        pass

    def get_modified_time(self, name):
        pass

    def _open(self, name, mode='rb'):
        file = bucket.files.get(file_name=name)
        return file.download()

    def _save(self, name, content):
        name = self.generate_filename(name)
        name = "photos/" + name
        bucket.files.upload(contents=content, file_name=name)
        return name

    def generate_filename(self, filename):
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(filename)
        m = hashlib.md5()
        m.update(filename.encode("UTF-8"))
        return m.hexdigest() + file_extension

    def url(self, name):
        url = re.sub(r'b2api.*$', '', bucket.connector.download_url)
        url += "fotoplatform/" + name
        return url
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I've come up with a reasonable solution for this. I am creating a `TempPhoto` object with the photo file and other data I want to store with it. I store the photo on the server that Django is running on, in a `temp_photos` folder. Then I call a Celery task after the `TempPhoto` object is created and return a success response to the uploading browser.

The Celery task starts running in the background in the meantime, this creates a real `Photo` object and also generates the required thumbnails with the `make_thumbnail(self)` method described in my question. It then uploads all things required to B2. This can take up to 1 minute per photo with the sometimes slow API of Backblaze B2 but that does not matter too much as it is now running asynchronously in the background, independent of the Django webserver. At the end of this task the `TempPhoto` object is deleted and the locally stored photo in `temp_photo` is also removed.

I am looking into a way to relay the task progress back to the end user, but that is not too important right now.